# Array return issue

Tags: c++, arrays

I've made a tree class and a global function. I have made an array in the Tree class function 'insert' which is initialized using another array 'returned' from the global function. The array returned from the global function works fine within that function, however, it gives garbage values upon being assigned to the array(required array) inside the 'insert' function.

Here's the code 
(Isn't full due to plagiarism issue)

```
float *func_calc(...,...,...,...)
{
    float decisions[17] = { 0 };
    ....
    .......
    ......... // Put Values into the 'decisions' array
    return decisions;
}

class Tree
{
    ..
    ....
    .....

    insert(...,...,...,...)
    {
    ....
    float* fun_array = new float[17];
    float min_num = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            fun_array = func_calc(...,...,...,...); // same arguments as the    insert function arguments
            min_num = fun_array[0];
        }
        else
        {
            fun_array = entropy(i, array, arraysize, rD);
            float num = entfun_array[0];
            if (num  < min_ent)
            {
                min_num = num ;
            }
        }
    }
}
};

int main()
{
   Tree T1;
   T1.insert(... , ... , ..., ... );
}
```

Comment: Youre returning a pointer to a local variable, this is UB.

Comment: Can you put some effort in formatting your code?

Comment: use a vector of floats and return that

Comment: by local variable you mean the `fun_array` ? How

Comment: Yep SunAns, if you're not using `clang-format`, drop what you're doing and set up `clang-format` on your system. It. will. change. your. life. ;)

Comment: Don't know whats that honestly

Comment: `clang-format` is a tool which will automatically format your code to a style you specify. Here's an online demo - paste some code into that. http://format.krzaq.cc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning `pointer` to a temporary, local variable (which causes undefined behaviour), allocated on a stack, which gets deallocated when the function returns. It's better if you create an `array` first and then pass it to the above function.

Or, an *unpreferable, dangerous*, method can be to allocate memory on the heap to the `decisions` array inside the function, to reserve non-local memory :

```
float *decisions = malloc(17*sizeof(float));
```

But then, you need to deallocate (`free()`) the memory allocated using `malloc()`, otherwise, there will be a memory leak.

Comment: This answer should be replaced with dots due to plagiarism issue.

Comment: See the updated answer. @SunAns

Comment: You too. Consider adding dots if you want. (and possibly upvoting too) :) @Slava

Comment: @Jarvis I cannot, sorry. Nothing personal but I consider upvoting answers to extremely low quality questions as support to that questions as well.